# What is this cursive font?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

The place where I worked had this font, I can't remember the name it nor can I make any "font finder" recognize this one to identify:

[image]

Also, if you know any font with similar "f", "s" and "r" letters it would be really nice.

Comment: This is too low quality image to font identifier sites.. The tails are either custom drawings or different characters from a companion font that is designed to give some decoratives, if wanted. Have you sharper image? See how differet are the two s characters. There's surely some custom edits done. A hint: Drag the characters apart for a font identifier site.

Answer (score 3):

This is a font called [Veryberry Script](https://creativemarket.com/mosquito/89806-Veryberry-Script):

[image]

Please note, the swashes at the beginning and ends of the words are included as part of the font when purchased.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to find an exact match, but browsing through "Script/Handwritten" on dafont.com reveals many similar free fonts.

[See for yourself here.](https://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=603&text=flour%20sugar%20cats)

For example:

Bromello:

[image: Bromello]

Zaheera:

[image: Zaheera]

Druchilla:

[image: Druchilla]

Daydreamer:

[image: Daydreamer]

And many more!